# Запрос в запросе MySql

Tags: php, циклы, mysql

Есть вывод данных из таблицы. Хотел бы узнать, ничего, что в самом цикле **при выводе записей из таблицы support**, используется функция для **вывода кол-ва комментариев(get__num__comments)**, в которой 1 запрос к БД? Правильно ли это?

```
// функция вывода кол-ва комментариев
function get_num_comments($id) {
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `support_comments` WHERE `support_id` = '$id'");
 return mysql_num_rows($query);
}

// выводим записи из таблицы support
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `support`");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
 echo get_num_comments($data['id']); // получаем кол-во комментариев к каждой записи
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запросы в цикле вообще плохая идея. В данном случае достаточно одного запроса вида:

```
select support.*, count(support_comments.id) as num_comments
from support
left join support_comments on support.id=support_comments.support_id
group by support.*
```

там, где звездочки, перечислите (и в select и в group by) необходимые поля.

ЗЫ mysql разрешает не писать group by, но это для тех людей, которые знают, что вернется, а не для тех, кому лень писать перечень полей из select'а.

Comment: Гм, а вот оба объединить я не догадался) Плюсану)

Answer (score 1):

Плохой вариант: во-первых, незачем брать все данные из таблицы; во-вторых, запросы можно объединить:

```
// примерная функция (мб сразу будет работать)
function get_num_comments_all($ids = array()) {
  if (empty($ids)) return array();
  $result = array();
  $q = mysql_query('
    SELECT 
      `support_id`, 
      COUNT(`support_id`) AS Count
    FROM `support_comments`
    WHERE `support_id` IN ('.implode(', ', $ids).')
    GROUP BY `support_id`;
  ');
  while ($rec = mysql_fetch_object($q))
    $result[$rec->support_id] = $rec->Count;
  return $result; // массив в формате support_id => Count
}
// далее собираем id
$ids = array();
$items = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `support`");
while($data = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
  $items []= $data;    // собираем массив записей
  $ids []= $data->id;  // и отдельно айди
}
// получаем кол-во комментов для всех записей
$comment_sum = get_num_comments_all($ids);
// вывод
foreach ($items as $item) {
  echo $item->id.': '.$comment_sum[$item->id].'<br />';
}
```